# Apache Startup Failure

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, vmware, xampp, visual-c++

I am using vm ware and have installed xampp. While I start apache, it shows this:

```
2:42:36 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
2:42:36 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
2:42:36 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
2:42:36 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
2:42:36 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
2:42:36 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
2:42:36 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

And after that, I receive a system error:

```
The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer
```

So I started to install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (64-bit)
and uninstall all old version, but it shows up a setup failure as:

```
Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
```

I also got this log error from the installation:

```
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i001: Burn v3.7.3813.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\130449492\Downloads\vc_redist.x64 (1).exe, cmdline: ''
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\130449~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20160518144544.log'
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\130449492\Downloads\vc_redist.x64 (1).exe'
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\130449492\Downloads\'
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKey, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Present, cached: Complete
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Present, cached: Complete
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64 >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT64 = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:44]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Repair
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\130449~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20160518144544_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.log'
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\130449~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20160518144544_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.log'
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Present, default requested: Repair, ba requested: Repair, execute: Repair, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Present, default requested: Repair, ba requested: Repair, execute: Repair, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Repair, ba requested: Repair, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:47]i300: Apply begin
[0F28:074C][2016-05-18T14:45:48]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0F28:074C][2016-05-18T14:45:53]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0F28:074C][2016-05-18T14:45:53]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0F28:0FE4][2016-05-18T14:45:53]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi.
[0F28:0FE4][2016-05-18T14:45:53]i304: Verified existing payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\cab1.cab.
[0F28:0FE4][2016-05-18T14:45:53]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi.
[0F28:0FE4][2016-05-18T14:45:53]i304: Verified existing payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\cab1.cab.
[0F28:0FE4][2016-05-18T14:45:54]i304: Verified existing payload: Windows7_MSU_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\42D5BEC7DDFBD49E76467529CBC2868987BF8460\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu.
[0F28:074C][2016-05-18T14:45:54]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:57]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0F28:074C][2016-05-18T14:45:57]i325: Registering dependency: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64
[0F28:074C][2016-05-18T14:45:57]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:58]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0F28:074C][2016-05-18T14:45:58]i325: Registering dependency: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64
[0F28:074C][2016-05-18T14:45:58]i301: Applying execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\42D5BEC7DDFBD49E76467529CBC2868987BF8460\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\42D5BEC7DDFBD49E76467529CBC2868987BF8460\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart'
[0F28:074C][2016-05-18T14:45:59]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:59]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:59]i319: Applied execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:45:59]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[0F28:074C][2016-05-18T14:45:59]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[0F28:074C][2016-05-18T14:45:59]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0268:05F8][2016-05-18T14:46:00]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Where can I go from here in order to install the correct version, and get Apache to start?

Answer (score 0):

The error code `0x80240017` means `WU_E_NOT_APPLICABLE - Operation was not performed because there are no applicable updates`. This means the MSU can't be installed because:

- requirements to install the update are missing
- update is already installed
- update is superseded (already replaced with newer version)

Look if you ave the update [KB2999226 (Universal C Runtime)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226) already installed and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

0) exit **XAMPP** completely from the taskbar
1) unzip/extract **Visual C++ Redist Installer V38a.exe** using **7zip** [google for them please]
2) look for the folder in this path - which is the folder you just have extracted:

> \Visual C++ Redist Installer V38a\vcredist_x86_2015\System

3) Select All (CTRL+A) the files in that folder and Copy (CTRL+C)
4) Go to Xampp root folder where XAMPP exes are, as Xampp control panel and Paste all those files (CTRL+V)
5) Start Xampp Control Panel
6) Start Apache
7) Relax.
ps. if port 80 fails replace it with 8080 in apache's config then httpd.conf and the siblings of it. tomcat's config uses port 8080 therefore you have to change that too to a different number
the logic stands that poor apache is trying to find the file entitled 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll' but it cannot find it anywhere, therefore if it does not have it, it won't start without it, and the program will output the message as of what it needs in order to function correctly.
cheers
Georgian